# Updating a model: timestamps set to FALSE not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5.2 model with the static `updateByHash()` method:

```
class SDNotificationMessage extends Eloquent {

    public static function updateByHash($hash) {
        $notifications = self::where('notification_id', 5)->whereRaw('MATCH(hash) AGAINST("'.$hash.'")');

        if ($notifications->count() === 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $notifications->update(array('foo_column' => 'bar_value'), array('timestamps' => false));
        }
    }
}
```

The update in the `else` above should **not** update the records' `updated_at` column. The update is called on a result from the model, and according to **[this signature](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_update)**, I should be able to use it just fine. No errors are thrown, but the timestamps get touched.

What am I doing wrong? Is the fact that the method is static a problem?

I found the solution on **[Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/use-update-without-updating-timestamps)**.

Comment: When getting rid of the array('timestamp') in the update method and try     $notifications->timestamps = false, and run the update method after - does this work (just for the sake of testing if the timestamp is getting recognized)?

Comment: Tried the method - doesn't work, unfortunately.